# Using a DNN container breaks the responsiveness of bootstrap bases skin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, dotnetnuke

I have made a DNN skin based on Twitter bootstrap. It is quite basic

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>


<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGO" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Logo.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="SEARCH" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Search.ascx" %>
<cut>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="Meta" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Meta.ascx" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>
<%@ Register Src="topLogo.ascx" TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="topLogo" %>



<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="bootstrapInclude" runat="server" FilePath="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="bootstrapCSS" runat="server" FilePath="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="14" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="DnnCssInclude2" runat="server" FilePath="bootstrap/css/cq.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="14" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="DnnCssInclude1" runat="server" FilePath="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="14" />
<dnn:META runat="server" Name="viewport" Content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />


<!-- The main container. -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <dnn:topLogo runat="server" id="topLogo" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="contentPane" class="contentPane span12" runat="server"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
       <div class="span12 lichtblauw">
            &nbsp;
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="span12 blauw">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1">
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <dnn:COPYRIGHT runat="server" id="COPYRIGHT" />
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And it works fine.

Now if i use the following container:

```
<%@ Control language="vb" CodeBehind="~/admin/Containers/container.vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.Container" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TITLE" Src="~/Admin/Containers/Title.ascx" %>
<div class="pleunscontainer"><h2><dnn:TITLE runat="server" /></h2><div id="ContentPane" runat="server"></div></div>
```

Somehow if I use this container to add a simple module, the code breaks and the responsiveness of the bootstrap framework comes to a halt.

Any ideas what is causing this to happen? As soon as I take the container off (leave it empty) or use the DarkNight containers it is working fine, I am puzzled...

**Update**

Page with my skin and my container
[Removed Link]

Page with my skin and default darknight container (simple)
[Removed link]

You will notice that upon changing the width of the browser, the second one will resize and go to a mobile friendly version. The first does not.

Comment: I'd start looking at the generated HTML content after the fact.  Is this just a HTML module?

Comment: Yes, its plain HTML just a title and text; nothing else. The funny part is that with another container it works

Comment: Is it the container or the module/content causing it to break?

Comment: If I use the module with a different container (default from Dark Night) it does NOT break, so my guess is that it is the container that breaks it

Comment: I would like to see broken HTML instead of `<%#` . I mean rendered

Comment: @SurjithSM: I added links in the Original questions to two pages: one with my container and one without where you can see the difference. To paste the entire HTML is a bit much

Comment: @Pleun Thanks for the links. I found the issue, Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, Thanks for posting the Links, I understood the issue now.

The issue is with the `<head>` part.

Please put your `responsive.css` after `bootstrap.css`. Now its above it, So it making issue. I just changed it in DevTools and working fine.

**OLD HTML**

```
<link href="/dotnetnuke/Portals/_default/Skins/CQ/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css?cdv=24" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/dotnetnuke/Portals/_default/Skins/CQ/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?cdv=24" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**CHANGE IT TO**

```
<link href="/dotnetnuke/Portals/_default/Skins/CQ/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?cdv=24" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/dotnetnuke/Portals/_default/Skins/CQ/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css?cdv=24" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

That's it. Your issue will resolve now.

Comment: +1 This is a start for sure. However, as you can see in the skin, the responsive.css is after the bootstrap.css; so why does adding a container change the order of the cSS? And why does it not change with another container

Comment: @Pleun Are you sure it is changing automatically? Can you change it manually?

Comment: I'm looking at the source on that page and I see that RESPONSIVE comes BEFORE bootstrap.min, which would be what Surjith refers to. Make sure you are looking at the actual includes, not the comments that CDF inserts. In DNN you can control the "priority" for your CSS files, you might need to define that to force the order correctly. (Update, in my browser's html editor I moved the CSS order and that does correct the issue)

Comment: @Pleun Yes, As @ChrisHammond mentioned, Can you check the priority. Now I can see `Priority="14"` for both CSS

Comment: I changed the CSS prio and it works! I voted for your answer but cannot award the bounty untill 1 hour later